# Channels in CNN/GAN

Tags: neural-network, keras, gan

I found this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/generating-modern-arts-using-generative-adversarial-network-gan-on-spell-39f67f83c7b4) about art generation which uses GAN architecture to generate art. Let's move to part where we define our generator model.

```py
def build_generator(noise_size, channels):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4 * 4 * 256, activation=”relu”,       input_dim=noise_size))
    model.add(Reshape((4, 4, 256)))
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding=”same”))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Activation(“relu”))
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding=”same”))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Activation(“relu”))
    for i in range(GENERATE_RES):
         model.add(UpSampling2D())
         model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding=”same”))
         model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
         model.add(Activation(“relu”))
    model.summary()
    model.add(Conv2D(channels, kernel_size=3, padding=”same”))
    model.add(Activation(“tanh”))
    input = Input(shape=(noise_size,))
    generated_image = model(input)
    return Model(input, generated_image)
```

I understand why we increase input to `4x4x256(model.add(Dense(4 * 4 * 256, activation=”relu”, input_dim=noise_size)))`, but generator returns image with shape 4x4x256. How to work with this image? What's going on? As i think, we can work only with gray(1 channel) images and RGB images(3 channels).

Answer (score 1):

The number 4 has nothing to do with the number of channels but is simply used to define the dimension of the latent space (which is 2048 in total, `4 x 4 x 256`). The generator outputs an image of shape `(128, 128, 3)`, the height and width of the images are 128 pixels and the images have 3 channels. This can be seen when defining the last layer `Conv2d` layer of the generator:

```
model.add(Conv2D(channels, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
```

The number of channels/filters for this layer is defined by the `channels` variable, which is an argument for the `build_generator` function. When this function is called later on you can see that the value provided is `IMAGE_CHANNELS`, which is set to 3 at the start of the article.

Nevertheless, it is possible to work with images with 4 channels. These images have a fourth dimension which represent the alpha in addition to red, green, and blue (RGBA).